# $\langle Tx,x \rangle=0$ proof

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

If $T$ is a bounded operator on a hilbert space $H$ and $\langle Tx,x \rangle=0$ for all $x$ in $H$, then $T=0$.

I'm considering what we can conclude if $\langle Tx,x \rangle=0$ for all $x$ in some subspace $D$ of $H$. Am I right in thinking that it's not enough or indeed necessary for $D$ to be a hilbert space for us to conclude that $T$ is zero on $D$? What we need is that $D$ is a subspace and $D$ is $T$ invariant i.e. $T(D)$ is contained in $D$

Comment: That suffices, yes: Replace $D$ with its closure. Since $D$ is $T$-invariant, and $T$ is continuous, then the closure of $D$ is also $T$-invariant. Now the result follows since the closure of $D$ is itself a Hilbert space.

Comment: It has been mentioned earier (it seems the post was deleted?) that the statement as such is only true on complex Hilbert spaces. And $T$ should be linear, of course.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is if $D$ is merely a closed subspace of $H$, the result doesn't hold does it? $D$ must be T invariant. @AndresCaicedo

Comment: What if $T = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$?  Then $\langle Tx,x\rangle = 0$ for all $x$, but $T \ne 0$.

Comment: @Thomas Well, of course $D$ closed is not enough. Consider an orthogonal projection on $\mathbb C^2$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: that's why real Hilbert spaces are a bad idea.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Nothing wrong with real Hilbert spaces, just gotta work with self-adjoint operators.

Comment: Those complex numbers always mess me up!!  Sorry guys.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $D$ being closed has nothing to do with it @AndresCaicedo. $<Tx,x>=0$ for all $x$ in $D$ implies $T=0$ on $D$ precisely when $D$ is a subspace of $H$ and $T(D)$ is contained in $D$. This can be seen easily if you proof by the polarization identity. Then at the end of the proof you get $<Tx,y>=0$ for all $x,y$ in $D$. Then you need to be able to set $y=Tx$ so you need $Tx$ in D. So the OP is pretty much correct.

Comment: I know the condition does not matter, as the argument in my comment shows. Since the OP knows the argument in the closed case, and the general case follows trivially from it, it seemed to be the shortest route to verify the result. (Anyway, pinging does not work on answers.)